# Numpad behaves like arrow keys since upgrading to 13.10

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, 13.10, numpad

On my Samsung NP305E5A-A05US laptop, the numpad, except for the 5 key, has started acting like the arrow keys(6 moves the cursor right, 8 moves the cursor up, etc). However, holding the Fn key makes it work normally. NumLock only toggles the 5 key.

Answer (score 2):

You must have your numpad not locked. If you have the numlock button, just press it, if not you can use

```
  numlockx on
```

to install it : `sudo apt-get install numlockx`

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on the System Menu
2. Go to Preferences sub menu
3. Select Keyboard
4. Click on the Mouse Keys tab
5. Uncheck "Pointer can be controlled using the keypad"

Comment: That box was already unchecked. Perhaps I should clarify: By "cursor" I meant the blinking text cursor, not the mouse pointer. As I said before, the numpad behaves exactly like the arrow keys. It can scroll up or down on a webpage, navigate menus, and anything else the arrow keys can do.